# Dotnet Core: How to get configuration from an external library

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs

I am writing an Azure WebJob library.  Each function of a WebJob is standalone, and does not get passed any context with the calls to it.

I use Azure Storage for Tables and Queues with my library and so I need access to configuration to get the connection info.  I know that the configuration is attached to the JobHost in the main app, but how do I get to that configuration from an outside library?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add connectionstring to your Queues and Table library? In azure webjob you do not need to do it. You could add `appsetting.json` or bind to `IConfigurationRoot` object. You could refer to this [article](https://nguyentoanuit.wordpress.com/2018/06/18/create-azure-webjob-in-net-core/). If I understand wrong, please correct me:)

Comment: I also need to be able to read any app setting.  For example, I need to be able to specify a setting in config for the location of a folder that my library needs to write output to.  Without direct access to the IConfiguration instance, I don't know how to get to that information.

Comment: What the mean about ` I need to be able to specify a setting in config for the location of a folder that my library needs to write output to.` Could you tell me more about your idea. I could not get your point.